# I am trying to create a clone of Youtube app & using Youtube API v3 how to get list of thumbnails with info what has videos on original Youtube page?

Tags: api, youtube, thumbnails, channel, logos

I am using a request:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&type=video&q={search value}&maxResults=3&key={key}`
```

This way I am getting json with info about video thumbnails and descriptions what i need but I don't have an url to channel picture and don't have infro how many views has a video.

I found the way to get the info about channel URL logo in separate request

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId={id}
```

but it doesn't look right to make additional separate requests for every single logo of the list and Views statistics.

Also, is it possible to get in the same request for embedded video URL's as well?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, it's impossible from a search query `q=${searchValue}` to get the associated channel thumbnail URL in a single request.

Comment: I paid attention to it in the beginning, but every time I put 2 part parameters together in the same request I am getting an error from API .. this is the main problem .. but separate requests work... I just thought it would be possible to make just one request instead of many ones for each video that was the main point of the question

Comment: Could you share us an example of request with 2 `part` parameters which isn't accepted by the API?

Comment: For example: I tried this way: url: `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&part=statistics&q=${$searchValue}&maxResults=9&key=${YOUTUBE_API_KEY}`,

Comment: If [Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) was supporting both `part` `snippet` and `statistics` you should write it `part=snippet,statistics`, not as you did. However [Search: list#part](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#part) only supports `snippet`. The API forces you to first make a call to `search?part=snippet&q=${searchValue}` and then another call to `videos?part=snippet,statistics&id=${videoId}` where `${videoId}` was obtained in the first call to `search?part=snippet&q=${searchValue}`.

Comment: In other words, for my very first question, was s simple answer: I did it correctly the way I show in my question and it is impossible to get this info with just one request? That's what are you trying to say?

Comment: 1/2 Doing `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId={id}` to just obtain the channel thumbnail URL is like shooting on a cow with a bazooka (as you spent 100 of quota for this request) while `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&id={id}` costs only 1 of quota while returning you too the channel thumbnail URL. More generally you are right (sorry for not having made this point clear in my answer), it's impossible from a search query `q=${searchValue}` to get the associated channel thumbnail URL in a single request.

Comment: 2/2 [I edited my answer accordingly](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74750570/revisions). Here is more documentation about quota: [quota usage](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota) and [quota calculator](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost)

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much for your attention and patience with me!